# jQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error multiple modals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Right now I am having issues with a web page that uses modals and bootstrap so it has quit a bit of jQuery overhead. When you click on one of the modals the site freezes momentarily and then proceeds to load the data via sql procedure with php. When I go-to the Chrome Console I get the inevitable error:

[image: jQuery.10.3.min.js Maximum Call Stack Size]

I have two theories on where the problem is coming from:

**[A]** This page has three modals total in which the jQuery modal API uses the .modal class to make calls to the jQuery library when a button is pressed. Then a hidden modal receives its contents from loaded data from another single page with the same head references to all the same jQuery libraries? Here is a snapshot of some of the rest of the errors:

[image: Bad links to js files]

**[B]** The source code has the actual errors in the document.ready statement where the Console error list contains an error when jQuery.extends executes this jQuery function:

```
// position on 1st input capable field - special 'modal' logic added
$("input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
$( ".modal" ).focus(function(){$("input:visible:enabled:first").focus();});
```

Here is where the error code originates from I think:
[image]

If anyone else has some suggestions on how to Debug this issues any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
$( ".modal" ).focus(function(){$("input:visible:enabled:first").focus();});
```

To:

```
$(".modal input:not(:visible:enabled:first)").focus(function () {
    $("input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
});
```

Fixed the issue!